# Unable to push my app to Pivotal Web Services using cf push

Tags: cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

Here is my manifest.yml

```
  ---
applications:
- name: multi
  memory: 128M
  host: multi
  instances: 1
  path: H:/Computer Science/Web Technology/Node.js/multi/
  command: node app.js
```

I have also created the .cfignore file with node_modules/ in utf-8 format

But still getting this error

```
    FAILED
Error uploading application.
open H:\Computer Science\Web Technology\Node.js\multi\node_modules\grunt-con
b-qunit\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\node_modules\phantomjs\node_modules
-extra\node_modules\rimraf\node_modules\glob\node_modules\minimatch\node_mod
s\brace-expansion\node_modules: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I have no idea how to resolve it.

Comment: You mean Bluemix, right?

Comment: No ,its [Pivotal](https://run.pivotal.io/) but its almost similar to bluemix. They have also given creating .cfignore file and then pushing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you delete `node_modules` directory (or move to a different directory) and try again? If that works, I would [download](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pmuellr/bluemix-private-packages/master/.cfignore) the .cfignore from a working copy.

Comment: .cfignore is exactly the same format as the .gitignore file.  Here is an example of one I use a lot. https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/box-watson/blob/master/.cfignore

Comment: The problem seems to be that the path name is too long for Windows to process. I agree either deleting the node_modules folder or ignore it using the .cfignore shall resolve the issue.

Comment: @Jack-JunjieCai but in my case even having an .cfignore is not allowing me to push code. Also I have changed the temp directory location to remove the size constraints in windows.